# for loop inside switch statement in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to insert dynamic html element on section. 
For example, when I need three columns, I will call first for loop, which has 3 dynamic html on section. When I need two columns, I will call second for loop, which has 2 dynamic html on section. I think I need switch case to choose for loop that i need, but is it possible? for loop inside switch statement. Below,

```
switch(){
    case 1;
        for(var d = 0; d<3; d++){trigger}
    case 2;
        for(var a = 0; a<2; a++){trigger}
    case 3;
        trigger;
}
```

```js
$(function(){
     for(var d = 0; d<3; d++){
    $("#section").append("<article id='menu_'" + d + ">menu</div>");
   
    var cssObj = {
     'width' : '33%',
     'background' : 'blue',
     'float' :"left",
     'border':"1px solid #aaa"
    }

    
    $("#section").children("#menu_").css(cssObj);
   }

   for(var a = 0; a<2; a++){
    $("#section1").append("<article id='menu_'" + a + ">menu</div>");

    var cssObj = {
     'width' : '49.6%',
     'background' : 'yellow',
     'float' : 'left',
     'border' : '1px solid #aaa'
    }

    $("#section1").children("#menu_").css(cssObj);
   }

   $("#section2").append("<article id='menu_'>menu</div>")
   var cssObj = {
    'width' : '99.7%',
    'background' :'green'
   }

   $("#section2").children("#menu_").css(cssObj);




})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="section">
   
</div>

<div id="section1">

</div>

<div id="section2">

</div>
```

Comment: instead of having for loops that execute depending on which case is met. I would create a function that takes an int argument and specify that as the loop control variable.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is use the `switch` to define the number of times you will call the trigger and do the loop outside it:

```
switch(val){ // whatever val you're testing
case 1:
   n =3;
   break;
case 2:
   n =2;
   break;
case 3:
   n=1;
}
for(var d = 0; d<n; d++){trigger}
```

Comment: that's cool, but what if var cssObj is different? if three columns, width must be 33.33%. if two columns, width must be 50%. your suggestion looks like for loop trigger is the same.

Comment: I believe your problem isn't exactly "how to call `for` loop inside switch statement", but something related to make some structure of your page with dynamic sizes. I suggest you to edit your question and clarify what exactly you're trying to do.